# private microsoft blob access to Cloudflare

Tags: azure-blob-storage, cloudflare

I have a website under Cloudflare CDN. On the other hand, I have a Microsoft blob storage configured as private where I have some images and videos.
I need to config that blob to serve only that media to my website and prevent all other accesses. so for example :

https://test.blob.core.windows.net/1.jpg

should be accessible just from mydomin.com.

can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CORS for your blob if you wish to prevent access with different domains.

***In your storage account -> under setting resource sharing (CORS)***

[image]

```json
<Cors>
    <CorsRule> 
        <AllowedOrigins>http://*.contoso.com</AllowedOrigins>  
        <AllowedMethods>PUT,GET</AllowedMethods>  
        <AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-abc</AllowedHeaders>  
        <ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-*</ExposedHeaders>  
        <MaxAgeInSeconds>200</MaxAgeInSeconds>  
    </CorsRule>  
<Cors>
```

CORS provides a secure way to allow one domain you can enable CORS for each service. To enable CORS, you need to set the appropriate service properties using version `2013-08-15`

> **Once you've established the CORS rules for the service then, authorized request made against the service from another domain will be examined to determine whether it is allowed according to the rules you have specified**.

To more in detail ref the below ***documents***

[Windows Azure Storage and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) – Lets Have Some Fun - **GauravMantri**](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/)

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) support for Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services)